# Convert Actionscript 3 to Actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an problem to convert AS3 to AS2
Here is my AS3 code

```
submit.addEventListener("mouseDown", sendData);
function sendData(evt:Event)
{
 //for those using PHP
 var students:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/phpflash/new_student.php");
 students.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 var posts:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
 posts.Fullname = Fullname.text;
 students.data = posts;

  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
 loader.load(students);
}
```

Comment: "I have a problem" since you don't show any attempt to convert to as2 I'm guessing your "problem" is that you want somebody to do it for you.

Comment: I cant convert in the part 'function sendData(evt:Event)' and 'var students:URLRequest = new URLRequest' and the 'students.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;'

Comment: http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?831695-sending-value-from-flash-as2-to-php-script

Comment: `evt:Event` is for the **mouse click down** event so here you do the AS2 version of function for handling a mouse click. `URLRequest` is like `filepath = `is your other questions. And the `...Method.POST` is like the "POST" as used in your other questions when you say  `(filepath + "editmorfologi.php", variasi, "POST");`. Why are you even using (& struggling) with AS2 code in 2015? I recommend learning AS3 when you can (more options)...

Comment: Hello @VC.One can you help me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171467/result-update-database-from-flash?noredirect=1#comment56090641_34171467

Answer (score 0):

Like @VC.One said, you must learn `AS3`, `AS2` was dropped and actually Flash CC does not support it.

I do not code in `AS2` since many, many years. So this code could contain some errors:

```
submit.onMouseDown = sendData;

function sendData():Void
{
    var vars:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

    vars.Fullname = Fullname.text;

    var target:Object = new Object();

    target.onLoad = function(){

        trace("vars sended");

    }

    vars.sendAndLoad("http://localhost/phpflash/new_student.php", target, "POST"); 

}
```